# Why is it that $A=B[I]^b_a$ and $[I]^b_a=AB^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it that $A=B[I]^b_a$ and $[I]^b_a=AB^{-1}$ where a, b are basis vectors for $R^n$ and A=$[a_1 ... a_n]   B=[b_1... b_n]$ and $[I]^b_a$ is the identity matrix from a to b. My professor used this fact in a proof but I don't understand why it is true.

Comment: If you are content with an answer, please check it and maybe upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_j = \sum_{k=1}^nc_{jk}b_k$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$, then that means $a_j = Bc_j$, where $c_j = (c_{j1},\ldots,c_{jn})^T$. So,
$$
A = [a_1\dots a_n] = [Bc_1\dots Bc_n] = B[c_1\dots c_n].
$$
Now, $[I]_a^b = [c_1\dots c_n]$, so $A = B[I]_a^b$. The other one is false unless $A$ and $B$ commute.