# Prove that when two matrices satisfy $Span(A) \subset Span(B)$, there exists a matrix $C$ such that $A=BC$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=(v_1| ... |v_k)$ and $B=(u_1| ... | u_k)$ be two $n \times k$ matrices. If Span$\{v_1,..., v_k\}$ is included in Span$\{u_1,...,u_k\}$, prove that there exists a matrix $C$ such that $A=BC$.

I am a student and want to prove this homework problem. I simply don't know how to start it. Thank you.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/569362/721644) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3418416/721644).

Answer (score 3):

Just go through the definitions. What does "Span{v1,..., vk} belongs to Span{u1,...,uk}" mean? Can you express that in terms of a linear algebra equation? Can you apply that equation to each column of $A$? What do you get when you combine the equations for all the columns of $A$? Can you combine all of the equations into one linear algebra equation?